# Trying to achieve a simple algorithm

Tags: java, c, algorithm

I have N options, between 1 and thousands. For example, I will explain it with 3 options, but I need this algorithm to work for N options.

- A=30% possibilities
- B=50% possibilities
- C=20% possibilities

I need to get randomly one of these three options, but according to the probabilities.

I achieved it by generating a random number between 0 and 100, and I'm doing some heavy and ugly code to know when the number is between 0 and the A possibilities number, between the A possibilities and the B possibilities, etc.

Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code so we can see what you already did.

Comment: Suggestion: stay away from multi-language source files. It's bad when the languages are C and C++, it's much much worse when they are C and Java :)

Answer (score 5):

choose a random number in the range you need, start subtracting the probability of each option from that number until you reach 0. the last probability you subtracted is what you want.

```
int[] possibilities = new int[] {20,50,30};
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(100);
int i = 0;
for (i=0;i<possibilities.length; i++) {
  r -= possibilities[i];
  if (r <= 0)
    break;
}
System.out.println(i); // the index of the possibility
```

Comment: If the possibilities were [20,50,20,10] then the loop would always break on the first twenty and never the second twenty.

Comment: @JoeAxon why ?? where the loop breaks depends on r which is random. if r is 80 then it will break on the 2nd 20.

Comment: which is "slow" for large numbers of N

Comment: @PierreHabouzit it isn't "slow" it's O(N). since you have to read your input you can't do better than O(N).

Comment: @yurib Could you elaborate? I do not believe your statement is correct.

Comment: @user1123692 i was talking about single draw, if the process is repeated you're correct that it is possible to trade space for time.

Comment: You can speed it up if you sort largest to smallest as well. So make your array {50,30,20} and 50% of the time you won't get past the first option. Only 20% of the time would you reach the worst case of O(N)

Comment: @yurib yes, but I assume that it's going to be repeated a considerable number of times, so that pre-computed cost will easily be made up over time, especially if your weighing is heavy on one possibility. Imagine if you have a set like {60,4,3,2,1,1,1,1...1}

Comment: @yurib You certainly can do better than O(n), by storing cumulative probabilities and doing a binary search on them. I think it's safe to assume the same set of probabilities will be used more than once.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this that's performant even given a large number of distinct options - assuming you pick from the same set of options more than once - is to construct a table of cumulative probabilities, then do a binary search over them.

That is, suppose you have the following desired outcomes: [0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05]

We build a set of cumulative probabilities by making each element the sum of all preceding elements in the original list: [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 0.95]

To select an outcome at random, we generate a random number between 0 and 1 and do a binary search over the list to find the greatest index smaller than it. This will select each element in proportion to the gap between it and the preceding element, which is the amount of the original probability.

Answer (score 3):

How about generating a "map" of possibilities somthing like: a - 30, b - 80 (a + 50%), c - 100 (b + 20%)

m = [30, 80, 100]

Then you generate a number from 0 to 100 and start checking from a to c and stop on first true.

```
int[] m = {30, 80, 100};
Random rand = new Random();    
int r = rand.nextInt(100);
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){ 
    if (r < m[i]){
         // the i-th possibilty occured!
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because you have a sorted set so binary search could be used to quickly find required index instead of linear search

Answer (score 2):

Create a table with as many elements as your required granularity, eg. for 1% it will be 100 element table. 
Fill the table with your options according to your required probability distribution
Draw a random int the same range as your elements table. 
Use it as an index to fetch your option from the table.

Let's say (for simplicity) you only allow 10% changes and your given A,B,C options
Then 
(pseudocode)

```
chances[]={A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,C,C} 
index=random() //make sure you get an int number in the range 0..9 here  
myChance=chances[index]
```

It uses more memory as loop based on probability table, but it's O(1) which will make a difference for large N and if you need repeated draws

Answer (score 1):

Create an even larger array containing instances of values 1, 2, 3 ... in proportion to their desired frequency.  Eg, create an array of 100,000 entries, and if #342 is, eg, 7%, put 7 copies of 342 into your large array.  Then select a value randomly from the large array using a uniform random number and modular division.

(Note that the size of the large array will be 100 times the number of possibilities, if your probabilities are in integer % and add to 100.  For finer granularity the array must be larger.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the chances are stored in the ***chances*** array, you can use something like:

```
srand(time(NULL));
const double chances[] = {
    0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4
};  
const double sigma = 1e-6;
int i, max = sizeof(chances)/sizeof(double);
double cumulative = 0.0, random_value = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
for ( i = 0; i < max; i++ ) {
    cumulative += chances[ i ];
    if ( random_value - cumulative < sigma ) break;
}
printf( "Index of chance: %d\n", i );
```